# Data URI To Blob Corrupts Image

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen numerous posts on this and numerous answers, but I can't quite make it work.

I have a canvas that I save out to a base 64 encoded image which works great.

```
capture: function(callback) {
    var ctx, imgData, src;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    return src;
  }
```

I can then set an image src to the base 64 encoded string and everything works great.  When I try to convert that to a blob so I can download it, the downloaded file is then unreadable as an image format.

```
saveImage: function(dataURI) {
    var ab, bb, blob, byteString, i, ia, mimeString, _i, _len;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    } else {
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }
    mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (_i = 0, _len = byteString.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      i = byteString[_i];
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append(ab);
    blob = bb.getBlob(mimeString);
    return saveAs(blob);
  }
```

All of this code seems fine to me, but the resulting file is not recognized as a valid image when it downloads.

I have a feeling I have the escaping wrong in the data url, but I can't find where.

I'm using Chrome Canary for development.

Comment: I have WebKitBlobBuilder but no BlobBuilder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the charCode at position `_i`, not `i`.

```
  ia[_i] = byteString.charCodeAt(_i);
```

Comment: And that ladies and gentleman is how CoffeeScript can bite you if you aren't willing to read the JavaScript it outputs.